# ASP.NET MVC custom routing with default route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a bit of problem

I have an MVC site that is working just fine.

I wanted to have SEO friendly urls so I created custom routing that looks like this

```
{section}/{group}/{manufacturer}
```

since it has the same number of fields as the default route

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

i created in loop in RouteConfig.cs that goes to database and loops Sections table and creates custom routes like

```
FOOD/{group}/{manufacturer}
SPORT/{group}/{manufacturer}
CARS/{group}/{manufacturer}
```

and point it to the Sections controller.

It works just fine. The problem I have is that now i need to rename FOOD to FRESH-FOOD and i want to keep old links to FOOD working.

What would you recommend ? How can I solve this ?

Is there a better way to do route Section instead of custom routes ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this might be a good case for a custom route handler. In the `ProcessRequest` method below you can check for controller name of "FOOD" and redirect to "FRESH-FOOD" like this:

```
    public class CustomRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            return new CustomHttpHandler();
        }
    }

    public class CustomHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var routeValues = context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
            var controllerName = context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
            if (controllerName.ToLower() == "food") controllerName = "FRESH-FOOD";
            var controller = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().
            CreateController(context.Request.RequestContext, controllerName);
            if (controller != null)
            {
                controller.Execute(context.Request.RequestContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

When you create your custom routes use the `Route` constructor overload that takes an `IRouteHandler`